# how do we check value $new_value1 = $inputpecentw1.Text. this value can?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

****How do we change in code line $MaskedTextBox.PasswordChar = '*' for checking digit value input? how do we limit the input windows size for minus sign and one number or one number in powershell TextBox? 
We want that the user can only enter one sign(minus) and one digit or only one digit. 
And why we cannot use backspace in windows to remove old value?

how do we check value  $new_value1 = $inputpecentw1.Text during input in window? this value can

be only one nagative digit for example -5 and not more than -9 or positive

number for example 4 from 1 to 9 and 0

i generate program it does not work like design  after  $Save_Click = {

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$Form= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '800,800'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$textnamef1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$textPercent = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $inputpecentw1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox'

    $Read = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $Save = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $form_Load = {
         $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content 'c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml') | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
    }    
    $Read_Click = {

      $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content 'c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml') | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String

    }  
    $Save_Click = {






IF ($inputpecentw1.Text -eq '^(\d|-\d)$'){
$new_value1 = $inputpecentw1.Text
 [xml](Get-Content 'c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml' -Encoding UTF8)  | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("Percent", $new_value1) }; $_.Save('c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml') }       
}
Else{ $value=$inputpecentw1.Text 
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($value.ToString())
}        } 
     $form.Controls.Add($textnamef1)
     $form.Controls.Add($textPercent)
    $form.Controls.Add($inputpecentw1)
    $form.Controls.Add($Read)
    $form.Controls.Add($Save)
    $form.ClientSize = '800, 800'
    $form.Text = 'проценты'
    $form.add_Load($form_Load)
    $textnamef1.AutoSize = $True
    $textnamef1.Location = '80, 40'
    $textnamef1.Text = 'MIK_Autokontinent.xml'    
    $textPercent.AutoSize = $True
    $textPercent.Location = '120, 110'
    $textPercent.Text = 'Percent'
    $inputpecentw1.Location = '120, 140'
    $inputpecentw1.Size = '20, 20'
    $Read.Location = '20,740'
    $Read.Size = '100, 40'
    $Read.Text = 'Rread'
    $Read.add_Click($Read_Click)
    $Save.Location = '680,740'
    $Save.Size = '100, 40'
    $Save.Text = 'Save'
    $Save.add_Click($Save_Click)
    #Show the Form
    $form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: SO many questions. So masny powershell versions. I suggest you pick just one.

Comment: How do we change in code line $MaskedTextBox.PasswordChar = '*' for checking digit value input (one digit with minus or one digit)?

Comment: You probably want to use the `Mask` property to limit what can be entered https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I suggest you google "convert powershell to exe". There are _many_ results

Comment: It's a definition of the `System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox` .Net class with a C# sample. There's no Powershell sample, but you already have some code - can you see, referencing your existing code, how to set the `Mask` property? It's in the very first line of your code.

Comment: Have you investigated this? https://poshgui.com/

Comment: why $PSScriptRoot do not work if i use Win-PS2EXE.exe to convert .ps1 to exe ? windwos return error cannont find file C:\MIK_Autokontinent.xml but file \MIK_Autokontinent.xml is located in folder

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox` instead of the regular TextBox,
then assign the `Mask` property.

Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=netframework-4.8) for available masking.

Comment: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/… this is c# and where is powershell?

Answer (score 0):

## Part 1

This is the first line of your script. I've put it on multiple lines for clarity and I've added comments. Please read through and understand what it's doing.

```
# set the variable $form to a Form object
$form = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' 

# set the variable $MaskedTextBox to a masked text box object
$MaskedTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox 

# set the properties on the masked text box
$MaskedTextBox.PasswordChar = '*' 
$MaskedTextBox.Top = 200 
$MaskedTextBox.Left = 200 

# add the masked text box to the form
$form.Controls.Add($MaskedTextBox)
```

So, if you look at the link posted to you, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=netframework-4.8 
you can see that a masked text box has a `Masked` property that will  probably do what you want.

You need to set the masked property to something. Again if you read the doco it says:

> > `#`  Digit or space, optional. If this position is blank in the mask, it will be rendered as a space in the Text property. Plus (+) and minus (-) signs are allowed.

So you need to set that property like so:

```
# set the variable $form to a Form object
$form = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' 

# set the variable $MaskedTextBox to a masked text box object
$MaskedTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox 

# set the properties on the masked text box
$MaskedTextBox.PasswordChar = '*' 
$MaskedTextBox.Top = 200 
$MaskedTextBox.Left = 200 

# Set the masked property
$MaskedTextBox.Mask = "#"

# add the masked text box to the form
$form.Controls.Add($MaskedTextBox)
```

I'm not sure if you really want to set the PasswordChar property but I'll leave that up to you

I suggest you put some effort into understanding this, and understanding powershell further. Everything you need to know is online, although I admit it's difficult to find and understand when you're starting out.

## Part 2

I can't work out how to implement the - sign in the masked text box so here is a workaround with a check box

This is a nasty piece of code but hopefully it will get you started

```
# Forms type library
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Msgbox type library
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# Form
$Form= New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '400,400'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

# Input
$MaskedTextBox                  = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$MaskedTextBox.multiline        = $false
$MaskedTextBox.width            = 20
$MaskedTextBox.height           = 20
$MaskedTextBox.location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$MaskedTextBox.Font             = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$MaskedTextBox.Mask             = '0'

#Check Box
$chkNegative                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$chkNegative.text                = "-ve"
$chkNegative.AutoSize            = $false
$chkNegative.width               = 115
$chkNegative.height              = 20
$chkNegative.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,20)

# Button
$btnOK                           = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOK.text                      = "OK"
$btnOK.width                     = 60
$btnOK.height                    = 30
$btnOK.location                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(106,96)
$btnOK.Font                      = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

# Add controls to form
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($MaskedTextBox))
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($chkNegative))
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($chkNegative,$btnOK))

# register an event handler for the button
$btnOK.Add_Click({ btnOK_Click })

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog()

# This is called when the button is clicked
function btnOK_Click { 
    if ($chkNegative.CheckState){
        $value=$MaskedTextBox.Text

    }
    else {
        $value="-" + $MaskedTextBox.Text
    }
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($value.ToString())
}
```

Comment: I've answered one of your questions but it doesn't seem like you've made any effort to implement or understand it. I suggest you use https://poshgui.com/ to autogenerate some code. It will show you how to write code to capture change events in fields.

Comment: Please make some effort to resolve your original question before asking another one. I suggest you use http://Poshgui.com to autogenerate your intial code and work from there.

Comment: Here's a reference to all the maskedtextbox methods. Which one do you want? what are you trying to do? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.clearundo?view=netframework-4.8. In your existing code, `$form.Controls.Add($MaskedTextBox)` calls the `Add` method on the Controls collection. Use that format.

Comment: After all of the example code I posted above, you did not add `$MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "#"` to your generated code. I've just tried it myself and it doesn't quite work but I'll keep investigating

Comment: I've edited my answer with some code. Give it a go. _Take time to understand what it's doing_